# Error on mysql install on debian 10

Tags: debian, mysql

**Edit** : solved by `sudo apt-get purge mysql-common`

---

I want to install mysql on a debian 10.
For that I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10).

During installation a root password is requested.
Only impossible to log in as root on the mysql server so I wanted to uninstall it to reinstall it and change the password.

Now during the installation I no longer have the window to enter a root password for mysql and I have the following error:

```bsh
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
 mysql-community-client
 mysql-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have test a clean :

```bsh
sudo apt remove mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```